# APEX not allowing queries of 3 levels or more relationships

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I am having a dilemma of what kind of query shall I make

Imagine that I'm inside a Details View of an object named **Merchandise** and of course, with the scope of LWC coding here, the **recordID** is focused on the Merchandise's.

[image: Production]

I want to create a Lightning Tree where I can display the **Production Requests** related to the **Merchandise** and put the related **Purchase Requests** of these **Production Requests** as sub-trees.

But it seems Salesforce / APEX isn't allowing sub-queries of up to 3rd level.

Legend:
PR = Production Request
PuR = Purchase Request

Relationships
Merchandise has many Production Requests
Production Request has many Purchase Requests

Mechandise > Production Requests > Purchase Requests
(this is the database structure)

I tried querying this

```
List<Merchandise__c> merchanList = [SELECT ID (SELECT ID, (SELECT ID FROM Purchase_Requests__r) FROM Production_Requests__r) FROM Merchandise__c)]
```

And APEX is telling me that I can't query for more than 2 levels of relationship.

Can someone kindly give me a good query or work around for my desired SOQL please?
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do part of the tree structure manually anyway. [tree-grid](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tree-grid/documentation) requires usage of `_children` element for child nodes. Apex doesn't like variables that start with underscore. In that sense it doesn't matter that you can't write 1 elegant query for everything.

- you won't be able to name any related list `_children`
- you could create a custom wrapper class with field `children` and then JS-side loop through it anyway

So... it doesn't matter. Probably simplest is to do 2 queries:

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Production_Requests__r)
FROM Merchandise__c
WHERE Id = :...

SELECT Id, (SELECT ID FROM Purchase_Requests__r)
FROM Purchase_Request__c
WHERE Merchandise__c = :...
```

Have them as `Map<Id,Merchandise__c>, Map<Id,Purchase_Request__c>` (JS also has [Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)) and loop through them to make final data structure? For each child element in 1st map check if there are grandchildren in 2nd map...

**Alternatively** you could make it "bottom up" but that would mean making some smart `for` loops with breaks when needed.

```
SELECT Id, Production_Request__c, Production_Request__r.Merchandise__c
FROM Purchase_Request__c
WHERE Production_Request__r.Merchandise__c = :...
ORDER BY Production_Request__r.Merchandise__c, Production_Request__c, Id
```

**Yet another idea** - can you fake it? OK, you may want a root element for you tree - but it'll always be just 1 element, the single merch record. If you can fake it in JS - or even better, have multiple top-level elements - then it's simpler. You only need simple query on Production + Purchase requests, screw Merchandise level?